# When can Ruby classes have multiple superclasses

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

Why does the following piece of code run as I expect it to run? I was under the impression that a class can only have one superclass and putting something other than the original superclass at the time the class was first defined would raise a type mismatch exception.

```
class Test
end

class MyTest < Test

  def run
    p 'my test'
  end
end

class MyTest < Object

  def run
    p 'redefine my test'
  end
end

MyTest.new.run
```

Result

```
redefine my test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me (Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3) only if the second class declaration is inherited from `Object`. Any other attempt at MI throws the `TypeError`.

Also it does not change the inheritance of the class. So `MyTest.superclass` remains `Test` even after `class MyTest < Object`

I think it is because `Object` is the default `superclass` when a new class is defined.  From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new):

```
new(super_class=Object) → a_class
```

So when `Object` is given as the `superclass`  it is ignored in the mismatch check since it is not known if `Object` was a user input or the default value.

Answer (score 3):

Never. Ruby does *not* support MI (but see traits as a useful alternative).

Anyway, *this class redefinition is ill-defined* and will result in different effects depending upon the particular Ruby implementation. When I run the given code I get "TypeError: superclass mismatch for class .." (Ruby 1.9.2; with 1.9.3 the error appears delayed).

If the code in question does not result in such an error, inspect `MyTest.superclass` to see what the superclass *really* is after said redefinition: note that [`#superclass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass) returns a *single* class object, not a collection.

Here is counter-example arguing that this redefinition scenario does *not* add or indicate MI:

```
class A
   def a; "a"; end
end
class B
   def b; "b"; end
end
class C < A
end
# This may raise said TypeError, but if it does not then ..
class C < B
end
# .. either this will work
C.new.a
# .. /or possibly/ this will work
C.new.b
# If the redefinition added MI then /both/ would work.
# If such an implementation is found, please let me know!
```

(I can't get the above to work without raising said TypeError.)

Comment: While correct in the general case, there is a little subtlety in OP's question. I suspect @tihorn's answer is the correct one here.